# meteor dynamic template data context

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze, spacebars

This is a very simple repo, feel free to clone it to test a solution or comment on the commit if its an easy change I'm missing. https://github.com/Falieson/meteor-blaze-examples/commit/8e94f7008cecf647bb23269d9b92cbae49e2398a

I started with meteor create, tested the blaze-components package, and am now figuring out how to use `{{> Template.dynamic template=childTemplate data=this }}`.

The "hello" counter doesn't pass the value for the reactive variable down to the template, I thought it'd be accessible from `{{#with this}}` or {{this.count}}

Similarly I would expect the "info" template to render each of the links.

Thank you for your assistance!

---

It looks at first like there's an error where containerTemplate is receiving `counterData` as a variable named `data` but I'm trying to access it using `this`. When I change `containerTemplate.html` 's call to render the childTemplate too `{{> Template.dynamic template=childTemplate data=data}}` the template doesn't render.

Comment: Template.dynamic is used (e.g. by a Router) to dynamically render data by calling Blaze.render or Blaze.renderWithData which I did not find in your project. Where do you actually pass your data to the template?

Comment: Thank you - I was chasing my issue down the wrong path. Pretty much the whole commit is garbage, I just needed to remove "import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the changes I made in this [commit](https://github.com/Falieson/meteor-blaze-examples/commit/8e94f7008cecf647bb23269d9b92cbae49e2398a) are chasing data context passing for the wrong reasons. I wasn't receiving helper data in the rendered template but I was getting an error in my console that I thought I could ignore because **it wasn't causing any issues until trying to use Template.dynamic**

```
modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:231 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'meteor/templating'

 at makeMissingError (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:231)
```

Removing `import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';` from my `main.js` fixed the issue immediately.